# How do I create a list of parameters in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a PowerShell script that at the beginning of the program sets the limits for a value. Eg

```
$value1Min      = 1
$value1Max      = 99
$value1Interval = 100
$value1Post     = 125
```

Now I want to be able to handle any number of values​​, but I do not need copy code for each value. How do I create a list of parameters for each value? 
Eg (pseducode).

```
$info={{min      = 1
        max      = 99
        interval = 100
        post     = 125
       },
       {min      = 100
        max      = 1000
        interval = 10000
        post     = 548
       },
       {min      = 50
        max      = 100
        interval = 500
        post     = 452
       }
      }
```

I'm not so experienced in PowerShell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an array containing hashtables like this:

```
$info=@(
    @{
    "min"      = 1;
    "max"      = 99;
    "interval" = 100;
    "post"     = 125;
   },
   @{
    "min"      = 100;
    "max"      = 1000;
    "interval" = 10000;
    "post"     = 548;
   },
   @{
    "min"      = 50;
    "max"      = 100;
    "interval" = 500;
    "post"     = 452;
   }
  )
```

Example of how to get a value:

```
PS C:\Users\stackoverflow> $info[0].interval
100
```

You could also create a hashtable containing hashtables:

```
$info=@{
    "info1"=@{
    "min"      = 1;
    "max"      = 99;
    "interval" = 100;
    "post"     = 125;
   };
   "info2"=@{
    "min"      = 100;
    "max"      = 1000;
    "interval" = 10000;
    "post"     = 548;
   };
   "info3"=@{
    "min"      = 50;
    "max"      = 100;
    "interval" = 500;
    "post"     = 452;
   }
  }
```

Example of how to get a value:

```
PS C:\Users\stackoverflow> $info.info1.max
99
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import you parameters from an xml file and access them via a posh object.

Example : 
Xml file val.xml:

```
<Param>
    <Param1 min= '1' max= '99' interval = '100' post = '125'>
      </Param1>
      <Param2 min= '100' max= '1000' interval = '10000' post= '548'>
       </Param2>
       <Param3 min= '50' max='100' interval='500' post= '452'>
    </Param3>
</Param>
```

Import the xml file in you powershell console with this command :

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content val.xml)
```

Now you can access you data like this :

```
$xml.Param
```

output :

```
Param1                          Param2                          Param3                        
------                          ------                          ------                        
Param1                          Param2                          Param3
```

If you want to get param1 values :

```
$xml.Param.Param1
```

output:

```
min                     max                     interval                post                  
---                     ---                     --------                ----                  
1                       99                      100                     125
```

and then $xml.Param.Param1.min ...etc

When you will use the values in your code beware of types. 
Example :

```
PS > $xml.Param.Param1.min.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                           
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

You may need to force some type conversions.